# Не работает height css

Tags: css

Всем привет. Есть блок меню, которое выезжает, блок лежит непосредственно в body.

```
.menu_mobile {
height: calc(100%-65px);
display: none;
.sm(display, block);  //свои примеси, less, все дела
transition: .25s;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;


top: -100%;
left: 0;
background-color: red;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-bottom: 5px solid green;
  &-active {
      top: 65px;
  }
}
```

Вопрос: почему не работает `height: calc`? На выходе получаю такое чудо: 
[image: бред с calc]

Comment: Если это LESS, то есть вероятность, что он считает `100%-65px` и получает `35px` (да-да, именно так!). Пожалуйста, дайте полный пример и настройки вашего lessc (или gulp или webpack или less.js или что там у вас), чтобы мы могли воспроизвести вашу проблему и ответить точнее

Comment: Кстати, скриншот из веб-инспектора с выделенным проблемным элементом и CSS-атрибутами тоже не помешает, а то я могу оказаться не прав

Comment: @andreymal Юзаю `gulp-less` из `npm`, до этого никаких проблем не было, компиляция идет нормально.

Comment: "Никаких проблем" понимать как "раньше calc всегда работал"?

Answer (score 1):

добавьте пробелов `height: calc(100% - 65px)`

Comment: не помогло, насколько я знаю, пробелы тут не столь важны.

Comment: @Alexxosipov, пробелы как раз тут важны. Стандарт требует, чтобы `+` и `-` в `calc` были окружены пробелами.

Answer (score 0):

1. Выстоты в процентах работают только если у родительского элемента есть фиксированная высота. Убедись, что просто 100% работает.
2. Вокруг знаков `+` и `-` должны стоять пробелы: `calc(100% - 65px)`.
3. Убедись, что к элементу применяется этот стиль и он ничем не переопределён.

Comment: 1. родительский элемент - `body` 2. Сделано 3. Все верно

Comment: 1. это не важно, если стилей для него нет.

Comment: @Alexxosipov, `html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; }` добавь.

Comment: Добавил, ничего не изменилось. Понял, что проблема именно в calc, поскольку если поставить height 100%, все работает правильно.

Comment: Разобрался. И правда, проблема именно в less компиляторе. Он компилирует `calc(100% - 65px)` как `calc(35%)`